# Calculate volume of $V={\{(x,y,z)|x^2+y^2\leq z\leq \sqrt{6-x^2-y^2}}\}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

Calculate the volume of $$V={\{(x,y,z)|x^2+y^2\leq z\leq \sqrt{6-x^2-y^2}}\}$$

My attempt:

$x=r\cos \theta$,

$y=r \sin \theta$, $z=z$

From here we can calculate the boundaries of our variables:

$0\leq r\leq \sqrt6, 0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi$,
$r^2\leq z\leq \sqrt{6-r^2}$

The jacobian is $J=r$
$$vol(V)=\int\int\int 1{dxdydz}=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\sqrt6\int_{r^2}^{\sqrt{6-r^2}}|J|{dzdrd\theta}=2\pi\int_0^\sqrt6\int_{r^2}^{\sqrt{6-r^2}}rdzdr=$$
$$2\pi\int_0^\sqrt6r(\sqrt{6-r^2}-r^2)dr$$

Now we substitute $$t=r^2, dt=2rdr\implies\pi\int_0^6(\sqrt{6-t}-t)dt$$

But the correct answer should be $$\pi\int_0^2(\sqrt{6-t}-t)dt$$

Answer (score 1):

The intersection is incorrect, by your substitution $x= r\cos(\theta), ~ y = r \sin (\theta) $ we get:

$$\begin{aligned} r^2 &= \sqrt{6-r^2} \\&\implies r^4 = 6-r^2 \\& \implies r = \sqrt{2}, ~ - \sqrt{2} \end{aligned}$$

And *not* $0 \le r \le \sqrt{6}$